# There is an error when the number of entries is 6 or 10

Tags: c, getline, strtok

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE* ip;
FILE* op;

int main(int argv,char* args[]) {
    ip = fopen(args[1],"r");
    op = fopen(args[2],"wr");

    char *line;
    size_t len = 0;
    len = getline(&line,&len,ip);
    int arr_index = 0;
    int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int)*((len-1)/2));

    char *ptr = strtok(line, " ");
    while(ptr != NULL){
        arr[arr_index++] = atoi(ptr);
        ptr = strtok(NULL," "); //line대신 NULL
    }
    for(int i=0 ; arr[i] ; i++){
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
//Do not use sizeof() (Because this is the part of my code. Later I need to size this way instead of using 'sizeof'.
}
```

It works normally in other numbers, but only errors occur when it's 6 or 10. (Test from 1 to 30)

input: "1 2 3 4 5 6" -> output:"1 2 3 4 5 6 **1041**"

input: "1 2 3 4 5 6 " ->output: lab9: malloc.c:2401: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.

input: "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10" ->output : "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 **1041**"

input: "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 " ->output: "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10"

Comment: You need to initialize `line` to `NULL` before calling `getline()`

Comment: What is `op` for?

Comment: You should either allocate some memory to your line or initialize it to NULL so getline do that for you

Comment: Your loop termination condition in `for(int i=0 ; arr[i] ; i++){` is unreliable; the array is not zeroed when allocated.  Use `calloc()` to get zeroed memory.  Or use `i < arr_index` as the condition.

Comment: regarding: `int main(int argv,char* args[]) {
    ip = fopen(args[1],"r");
    op = fopen(args[2],"wr");`  always check `argv` to assure the user entered the expected number of command line parameters before accessing anything beyond `args[0]`  I.E.  `int main(int argv,char* args[]) {  if( argv < 3) { fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s inputFileName outputFileName\n", args[0] );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`
    ip = fopen(args[1],"r");
    op = fopen(args[2],"wr");

Comment: regarding: `int main(int argv,char* args[]) {
    ip = fopen(args[1],"r");
    op = fopen(args[2],"wr");`  Always check (!=NULL) the returned value from `fopen()` to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful (==NULL) then call: `perror( "fopen for input file failed" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  similarly if the `fopen()` for the output file fails.

Comment: regarding: `FILE* ip;
FILE* op;`  in general, the scope of a variable should be limited as much as possible.  Global variable are (usually) a very bad idea.  Suggest moving those variables to inside the `main()` function.

Answer (score 3):

`getline()` requires the the `line` pointer to be a pointer to an allocated buffer or `NULL`, so that it can call `realloc()` if the buffer isn't big enough. You never initialized `line`, so it's calling `realloc()` with an uninitialized value, which causes undefined behavior. Change the declaration to:

```
int *line = NULL;
```

When `line` is `NULL`, `getline()` will allocate the necessary memory for it.

Another problem is that the `for` loop stops when it gets to a null pointer in `arr`, but you never add a null pointer after finding all the tokens. Put

```
arr[arr_index] = NULL;
```

after the `while` loop.

Comment: There's also a problem with the loop termination condition in the printing loop.  See my [other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61954589/there-is-an-error-when-the-number-of-entries-is-6-or-10#comment109577859_61954589).